# RxJava dependent network calls for list and item

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

I have two network calls dependent each other. Following,

```
getBookList(): Single<List<Book>>

getBookCover(bookId): Single<Cover>
```

First, I need to get bookList first, then I call bookCover, because cover api needs bookId.

After that, I need to combine the result like `List<BookWithCover>` list.

How can I do that with RxJava? I have already searched flatMapIterable operator but I couldn't manage it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine a solution could be:

```
getBookList()
    .toObservable()
    .flatMapIterable { it }
    .flatMap { getBookCover(it.bookId).toObservable() }
    .map { /* here convert to BookWithCover */ }
    .toList()
```

Essentially, get the list of books and map it to an observable that emits each one. With that get the book cover for each one and map it to a `BookWithCover`. At the end, just put everything back into a list.

Comment: getBookCover is already a single observable, why did to convert an observable.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed one thing. We need to convert the single to an observable to be able to flat map it as an iterable apparently. Once you call `flatMap` we need to keep it an observable to emit more than a single item to `map`. I've edit my answer.